# How to write code for below problem using Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

hm contains name and Age of Employees.
How to find the names of all employees whose age > 25 using java 8 streams concept

I attempted like this

```
hm.stream().filter(x->Map.Entry.getValue(x)>25).collect(collectors.toList());
```

Could anyone correct me?

Comment: "I attempted like this hm.stream().filter(x->Map.Entry.getValue(x)>25).collect(collectors.toList());" - What was the problem with that?

Comment: Do you want to have map's value with v>25 ? so do like `hm.values().stream().filter(x -> x > 25).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Age of Employees? Is that a variant of Age of Empires? Cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get stream over Map directly. You can get `.entrySet()` of the map then filter by age and collect names in a list.

```
List<String> list = hm.entrySet().stream()
                                 .filter(x -> x.getValue() > 25)
                                 .map(e -> e.getKey())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I want to get list of all employees names  whose age>25

Comment: @medha Updated answer